# Get Youtube Video ID from html code with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to get all only youtube video ID from html code

look the (or multiple) object/embed code for youtube video

// html from database

```
    <p>loremm ipsum dolor sit amet enot
    <a href="link" attribute=""blah blah blah">anchor link</a>
    </p>

    <object width="425" height="344">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ou5eVl5eqtg&hl=es_ES&fs=1&"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ou5eVl5eqtg&hl=es_ES&fs=1&"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    allowscriptaccess="always"
    allowfullscreen="true"
    width="425"
    height="344">
    </embed>
        </object>

    <image src="path/to/image.ext" >
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... blah</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... blah</p>

    <object width="425" height="344">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ou5eVl5eqtg&hl=es_ES&fs=1&"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ou5eVl5eqtg&hl=es_ES&fs=1&"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    allowscriptaccess="always"
    allowfullscreen="true"
    width="425"
    height="344">
    </embed>
        </object>
<p>blah</p>
blah<br/>
blah<br/>
blah<br/>
```

Comment: ... and your question is? Did you produce any non-working code yet?

Comment: I founded this code on internet
preg_match('/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/',[youtubevidurl], $matches);
but not works in this case, i'm not versed on regex
sorry my english :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brazenly stolen from htmlpurifier's youtube plugin:

```
preg_match('#<object[^>]+>.+?http://www.youtube.com/v/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+).+?</object>#s', $markup, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 19):

There are generally two formats for YouTube video urls:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/[videoid]
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[videoid]
```

The "www.youtube.com" can be replaced by "www.youtube.co.uk", or other country codes, but as far as I've been able to determine, the video ids are the same regardless of the domain name.

The video id is an 11-character string that uses base-64 encoding.

Assuming you have code that will parse urls from an HTML document, you can determine if it's a YouTube video url and get the video id by using this regex (written in C#, but should be easily converted to php or anything else):

```
"^http://(?<domain>([^./]+\\.)*youtube\\.com)(/v/|/watch\\?v=)(?<videoId>[A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})"
```

This particular regex is specific to youtube.com.  Making it understand all the different country codes (youtube.co.uk, youtube.pl, youtube.it, etc.) is somewhat more involved.

Comment: I think you can figure out how to translate it.

Comment: You forgot this format: http://youtu.be/[videoid]  example: http://youtu.be/R_FOfQSarWY

Comment: @Anthony: at the time I wrote the response, that format didn't exist. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Perfect. This regex matches all it should match and nothing more.

Comment: A small bugfix - it does not consider querystrings: `"http://.+?(/v/|/watch\\?v=)(?P<videoId>[A-Za-z0-9_-]{11}).+?"`

Answer (score 12):

Actually, to completely capture all options, I found that WebFlakeStudio's solution is the best, with the following addition, to capture all 3 forms of *cough*client stupidity*cough*

(PHP)

```
preg_match('#(\.be/|/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=)([A-Za-z0-9_-]{5,11})#', $YoutubeCode, $matches);
if(isset($matches[2]) && $matches[2] != ''){
     $YoutubeCode = $matches[2];
}
```

I added the /embed, this should capture all. The Object, the URL and the Embed-option.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get embed link for youtube video, you can use the following code snippet:

```
$youtubeRegexp = "#(/v/|/watch\?v=)([A-Za-z0-9_-]{5,11})#";
$embedUrl = preg_replace($youtubeRegexp, '/embed/$2', $videoUrl);
```

For the current moment embed code is:

```
<iframe width="{width}" height="{height}" src="{embed_url}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Note: $videoUrl should be set to the original url prior to running this expression.

Answer (score 1):

I might get scolded for using a regex to parse html but given the circumstances maybe it's the best way to do it?

```
preg_match('~/v/([0-9a-z_]+)~i', $code, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

assuming the valid characters for a youtube video id are 0-9a-z_

Comment: it works! , but there is a way to do this safely, forcing only for youtube vids?

Comment: add youtube.com before the /v/