# How do I use Regex to find the ID in a YouTube link?

Tags: python, regex, youtube

when I try to extract this video ID (AIiMa2Fe-ZQ) with a regex expression, I can't get the dash an all the letters after.

```
>>> id = re.search('(?<=\?v\=)\w+', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIiMa2Fe-ZQ')
>>> print id.group(0)
>>> AIiMa2Fe
```

Comment: Same question, in PHP instead of Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773822/get-youtube-video-id-from-html-code-with-php .

Comment: Also, YouTube will be changing their URIs, so you need to be able to handle those as well: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/03/upcoming-change-to-youtube-video-page.html

Comment: See drewk's answer below for full youtube format coverage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the pattern for youtube hashes, but just include the "-" in the possibilities as it is not considered an alpha:

```
import re
id = re.search('(?<=\?v\=)[\w-]+', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIiMa2Fe-ZQ')
print id.group(0)
```

I have edited the above because as it turns out:

```
>>> re.search("[\w|-]", "|").group(0)
'|'
```

The "|" in the character definition does not act as a special character but does indeed match the "|" pipe.  My apologies.

Comment: is pipe allowed in a youtube ID? I don't think so.

Comment: From the docs:
"Some characters, like '|'  or '(', are special."

"A|B, where A and B can be arbitrary REs, creates a regular expression that will match either A or B."

"To match a literal '|', use \|, or enclose it inside a character class, as in [|]."

Comment: **youtube video id doesn't contain `|`** (pipe).

Comment: @SilentGhost Thanks, I had mistakenly believed the "|" (pipe) would act as a special character.  I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Intead of \w+ use below. Word character (\w) doesn't include a dash. It only includes [a-zA-Z_0-9].

```
[\w-]+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.search('(?<=v=)[\w-]+', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIiMa2Fe-ZQ').group()
'AIiMa2Fe-ZQ'
```

`\w` is a short-hand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` in python2.x, you'll have to use `re.A` flag in py3k. You quite clearly have additional character in that videoid, i.e., hyphen. I've also removed redundant escape backslashes from the lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

```
/(?:/v/|/watch\?v=|/watch#!v=)([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/
```

[Explain the RE](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%3F%3A%2Fv%2F%7C%2Fwatch%5C%3Fv%3D%7C%2Fwatch%23%21v%3D%29%28%5BA-Za-z0-9_-%5D%2B%29)

There are three alternate YouTube formats: `/v/[ID]` and `watch?v=` and the new AJAX `watch#!v=` This RE captures all three. There is also new YouTube URL for user pages that is of the form /user/[user]?content={complex URI} This is not captured here by any regex...

Answer (score 1):

Use the urlparse module instead of regex for such kind of things.

```
import urlparse

parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
if parsed_url.netloc.find('youtube.com') != -1 and parsed_url.path == '/watch':
    video = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed_url.query).get('v', None)

    if video is None:
        video = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed_url.fragment.strip('!')).get('v', None)

    if video is not None:
        print video[0]
```

**EDIT:** Updated for the upcoming new youtube url format.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = re.compile(r'.*(\-\w+)$')
>>> a.search('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIiMa2Fe-ZQ').group(1)
'-ZQ'
```