# trim url string. c#

Tags: c#, regex

how can i trim a youtube url so it only returns the video id for example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPqTW-9U9nU. how would i return VPqTW-9U9nU. this has to be for several url inputted. I would like to use regex but I do not understand it at all. so if somebody has a solution with regex could you explain it in abit more details  :)

Comment: answer: regex way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773822/get-youtube-video-id-from-html-code-with-php/1773972#1773972

Comment: this question is more about parsing the URL vs trimming it

Comment: I'll recommend my answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773822/get-youtube-video-id-from-html-code-with-php/1773972#1773972.  Note also that since I wrote that, YouTube added their URL shortener that gives URLs of the form `http://youtu.be/videoid`.  I use a separate regex for that: `http://youtu.be/(?<videoId>[A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})`

Answer (score 13):

Without doing any string manipulation you can use `Uri` and `ParseQueryString`

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPqTW-9U9nU");
var s = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query).Get("v");
```

Answer (score 2):

No RegEx needed in this case:

```
string url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPqTW-9U9nU";
string videoId = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("?v=") + 3);
```

Comment: +1, but only if v is always the last variable defined in the url. Otherwise something more substantial is required.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just stick with something simple?

```
string youTubeUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPqTW-9U9nU";
string id = youTubeUrl.Replace("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", String.Empty);
```

Regular expressions are handy, but sometimes overkill and can make your code harder to understand when you use them in places you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
string url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPqTW-9U9nU";
string video_id = url.Substring(0,url.LastIndexOf("=')+1);
```

The other answers look right, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `String.Split()`:

```
url.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2)[1]
```

Comment: I pray it would be not me that guy who will have to mantain it.