# Parse URL for video ID

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I used to embed YouTube video's via a link I have in a database.

YouTube no longer allows me to embed in this fashion. Instead, I need to extract the video ID from the URL I have stored.

Here is an example of the link:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72xSxQIRelc&amp;feature=youtube_gdata
```

The ID I need to extract is `72xSxQIRelc`. I know I could do something like:

```
string vidID = 
    preURL.Substring(preURL.LastIndexOf("v=") + 2,
    preURL.Substring(preURL.LastIndexOf("v=") + 2).Length -
    preURL.Substring(preURL.LastIndexOf("&feature")).Length)
```

I've seen some Regex stuff on here that does this. I'm wondering if my way is horribly inefficient, comparatively. I'm also not a regex kung fu wizard, so I'm not sure if the solutions I'm seeing are scalable if YouTube changes the URL structure (in this case, it's hard coded to require v= as well as &feature).

My solution still seems pretty hackish to me. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

---

**Added**

This app is wrapped in a **silverlight** solution, so I should mention that here.

One posted solution was to use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString. That looked like it was the answer, up until I discovered that Silverlight's implementation of HttpUtility doesn't include the ParseQueryString method.

Comment: then you should just update your database no?

Comment: Are all your YouTube URLs stored in that format? One of the problems with parsing YouTube URLs is that there's more than one style. If they are all in the same format, or at least have query string parameters, then parsing our the video ID is as easy as reading the parameters, as @user938528 pointed out.

Comment: Here's how I do it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773822/get-youtube-video-id-from-html-code-with-php/1773972#1773972

Comment: Jim - is my implementation wrong here? The result of the following Regex.Match is the URL through the video ID (e.g. youtube.com/v=12345678901) `Regex.Match(selectedVideo.PostLink, "^http://(?<domain>([^./]+\\.)*youtube\\.com)(/v/|/watch\\?v=)(?<videoId>[A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})")`

Comment: The `Match.Value` will contain the entire URL, yes. To get just the video id, examine `Match.Groups["videoId"].Value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

then you should just update your database **no**?

```
UPDATE 
    [VideosTable]
SET
    video_url = 
        SUBSTRING(
            video_url, 
            CHARINDEX('v=', video_url) + 2,
            CHARINDEX('&', video_url, CHARINDEX('v=', video_url)) -
            (CHARINDEX('v=', video_url) + 2)
        )
WHERE
    video_url LIKE '%youtube.com%';
```

Then you can simply use the video ID that comes from the Database...

if you are uploading the video ID from the hole link, use the `URI` object instead

```
Uri youtube = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72xSxQIRelc&amp;feature=youtube_gdata");
string videoId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(youtube.Query)["v"];
```

---

**Silverlight update**

Silveright lack two things, the support for the `ParseQueryString` part of the `System.Web.HttpUtility` and the `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`

So, why not just add that functionality yourself?

Because `HttpUtility` is already a `static` object you can't extend this, but you can easily create yourself something new:

```
public static class MyHttpUtilities
{
    public static System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>
        ParseQueryString(this string queryString)
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> r = 
            new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // remove extra noise
        queryString = queryString.TrimStart('?').Replace("amp;", ""); 
        // split up and fill up Dictionary
        foreach (string s in queryString.Split('&'))
        {
            if (s.Contains('='))
            {
                string[] par = s.Split('=');
                r.Add(par[0], par[1]);
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

and then use:

```
string videoId = MyHttpUtilities.ParseQueryString(youtube.Query)["v"],
       feature = MyHttpUtilities.ParseQueryString(youtube.Query)["feature"];
```

Comment: I updated original post to say I can't use the ParseQueryString as this is a silverlight app, and HttpUtility doesn't have that method in SL. I also want to save the entire URL in case I need it for anything in the future, so updating the db doesn't really fly for me. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: you should have tagged your question with the `silverlight` tag then! and **for anything in the future** is definatly saving **only the ID** as with only that, you can do everything today and tomorrow!

Comment: Yes, I should have after editing, my apologies. Obviously on the original one I didn't realize Silverlight was even going to come into play here. I don't want to save only the ID though, I just wanted to extract it from the URL that's returned from my DB.

Comment: **added** Silverlight Solution.

Answer (score 3):

Why make it so complex?

Just use what already exists. Its a url. Its been here for 30 years try this

http://www.stev.org/post/2011/06/27/C-HowTo-Parse-a-URL.aspx

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the HttpUtility class in Silverlight does not include the ParseQueryString. I'll update my post to include the fact that this is a silverlight app. Didn't think that would be relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using String.split() method:

```
    String[] splitedUrl=preURL.split("v=",StringSplitOptions.None);
    String[] splitedUrl2=splitedUrl[1].split('&');
    String vidID=splitedUrl2[0];
```

Then you'll have that vidID.

Comment: YouTube supports multiple URL formats. This will only work if the format is using query strings and the first one is the video ID.

Comment: edited: now it'll start with spliting the URL to two parts, where the second starts with "v=...", which is the videoID. then it'll split that part to {vidID,.....}.