# Regex to get youtube video ID from full <object>

Tags: php, regex, youtube

Had a look round but couldn't find a working (and recent) solution for this.

Using an API I am receiving a string like this:

```
<object width="600" height="338">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ItT88H3nAWw?version=3&feature=oembed"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ItT88H3nAWw?version=3&feature=oembed" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="600" height="338" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>
```

What would be a regular expression in PHP to extract just the video id? e.g. `ItT88H3nAWw`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Youtube Video ID from html code with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773822/get-youtube-video-id-from-html-code-with-php)

Comment: tried, seems to just return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `src` param from `embed` tag **WITHOUT** regexp. Then parse it in following way:

```
$youtubeUrl = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/ItT88H3nAWw?version=3&feature=oembed';

if ( preg_match('youtube\.\w+.*?v[/=](\w+)', $youtubeUrl, $matches) ) {
  $youtubeId = $matches[1];
}
```

This regexp will handle both:

- http://www.youtube.com/v/ItT88H3nAWw
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItT88H3nAWw

To convert HTML string to an object use `SimpleXMLElement`.

```
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement($htmlCode);
$youtubeUrl = $obj->embed->src;
```

Comment: As mentioned above, the entire <object> is returned as a single string from the API I am using.

Comment: new SimpleXMLElement doesn't seem to successfully parse.

**SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 1: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'**

Comment: Although simpleXMLElement didn't work, i used Simple HTML DOM parser for PHP to process the html and extract the url.

Answer (score 0):

[Regexp is ugly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html). Use something like: [getBetween](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/get-between.htm)('www.youtube.com/v/', '?version')

Ok, here another version. Assuming `$s` is your string and youtube does not change it's ID length:

```
$p = strpos($s, 'youtube.com/v/') + count('youtube.com/v/');
$id = substr($s, $p, count('ItT88H3nAWw') );
```

Comment: How would you extract the id from a string like this `http://www.youtube.com/v/ItT88H3nAWw` with that? The tricky thing is that youtube offer alot of different ways to present their video-id

Comment: See new version above. You could also search for `min(strpos($s, '?', $p), strpos($s, '"', $p))` to find the end of the id.