# PHP extract youtube video IDs from array of iframe/object embeds?

Tags: php, regex, dom, youtube

I have an array of youtube iframes/objects like so:

```
[0] => <iframe width="600" height="338" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/szL_PVuzWp0?fs=1&feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
[1] => <object width="600" height="338"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/jm1S43a-e3Y?version=3&feature=oembed"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/jm1S43a-e3Y?version=3&feature=oembed" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="600" height="338" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
[2] => <iframe width="600" height="338" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7fTploFSbXA?fs=1&feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
[3] => <iframe width="600" height="338" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vQSRNYgiuMk?fs=1&feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Note that the embed method can vary (usually `<iframe>`, occasionally `<object>`) (due to external data source).

How would I/what is the most reliable method to go about extracting the video URL (e.g. vQSRNYgiuMk or jm1S43a-e3Y) for each one?

Ultimately I want to end up with an array like so:

```
[0] => "szL_PVuzWp0"
[1] => "jm1S43a-e3Y"
[2] => "7fTploFSbXA"
[3] => "vQSRNYgiuMk"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Youtube Video ID from html code with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773822/get-youtube-video-id-from-html-code-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($arr as $i=>$a){
    $start = strpos($a, "/v/") + 3;
    if(!$start) $start = strpos($a, "/embed/") + 7;
    $qm = strpos("?");
    $length = $qm - $start;
    $new_array[$i] = substr($a, $start, $length);
}
```

Comment: close but results in e.g. '/v/jm1S43a-' or '/embed/szL_' (includes the prefixes in the 11 chars)

Comment: also, IIRC youtube urls can be 10-12 chars long.

Comment: this is a decent solution to this problem so thanks.

But a better solution in the wider context was to access the URL directly (added a param into external API), rather than inside HTML.

Answer (score 5):

**Don't** use regex please :

```
   $dom_document = new DOMDocument();

   $dom_document->loadHTML($html);

   //use DOMXpath to navigate the html with the DOM
   $dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom_document);

   // if you want to get the all the iframes
   $iframes = $dom_xpath->query("//iframe");

   if (!is_null($iframes)) {
      foreach ($iframes as $iframe) {
        if($iframe->hasAttributes()){ 
            $attributes = $iframe->attributes; 
            if(!is_null($attributes)){ 
               foreach ($attributes as $index=>$attr){ 
                  if($attr->name == 'src'){ 
                     $curSrc = $attr->value; 
                     //use regex here to extract what you want
                  } 
               } 
            } 
         } 
      }
   }
```

**Not** a complete solution. But you get the point...

Comment: Is it necessary to use DOM? Is this the easiest way to access the src string?

Comment: @samb You are effectively trying to parse html with regex. While it can be done, the end result will be a not so nice parser. With DOM you can't go wrong. If something changes in your html structure you are doomed if you are using a simple regex.

Comment: Absolutely agree with this solution. DOM method is always better.
Thanks for solution.

Comment: This is the answer in my book. Worked perfect. Thanks!