# Get URL from IFrame?

Tags: php, iframe, embed

I wanted to allow users to be able to add videos but I'm having an issue with one of the sites.

I will allow videos from Youtube, Vimeo, Vevo, Daily Motion and MTV.

The problem is for MTV. The URL is always different, so I was wondering if there ways to get the source value of an IFrame/embed code.

Example: MTV embed code is:

```
<div style="background-color:#000000;width:520px;">
<div style="padding:4px;">
<iframe src="http://media.mtvnservices.com/embed/mgid:uma:videolist:mtv.com:1687162/cp~instance%3Dfullepisode%26autoPlay%3Dfalse%26series%3D2211%26seriesId%3D29240%26channelId%3D1%26id%3D1687162%26instance%3Dfullepisode%26uri%3Dmgid%3Auma%3Avideolist%3Amtv.com%3A1687162" width="512" height="288" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<p style="text-align:left;background-color:#FFFFFF;padding:4px;margin-top:4px;margin-bottom:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;">Get More: 
    <a href="http://www.mtv.com/shows/teen_mom/season_4/series.jhtml" style="color:#439CD8;" target="_blank">Teen Mom (Season 4)</a>, <a href="http://www.mtv.com/videos/home.jhtml" style="color:#439CD8;" target="_blank">Full Episodes</a></p></div></div>
```

Is there a way I can get the IFrame source value out of that complete string?

I just want :

```
http://media.mtvnservices.com/embed/mgid:uma:videolist:mtv.com:1687162/cp~instance%3Dfullepisode%26autoPlay%3Dfalse%26series%3D2211%26seriesId%3D29240%26channelId%3D1%26id%3D1687162%26instance%3Dfullepisode%26uri%3Dmgid%3Auma%3Avideolist%3Amtv.com%3A1687162
```

Any help would be appreciated. The other video sources were simple since I was able to use the physical URL itself rather than the embed code.

Comment: DOMDocument seems like a pretty appropriate method, and worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244508/php-extract-youtube-video-ids-from-array-of-iframe-object-embeds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's valid HTML, so you can easily parse it with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
$root = simplexml_load_string($embed_code);
$url = (string) $root->div->iframe['src'];
```

Comment: thank you soo so much... worked perfectly! im still a noob was aware of the SimpleXML functions

Comment: This didn't work for me. I only iframe, no div. and so I tried $url = (string) $root->iframe['src']; Seemed like a good idea... Ended up using DOMDocument instead.

Answer (score 2):

To do this it's quite easy, all you need is this one line of code.

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").src
```