# Get Youtube Id from Youtube Embed URL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to get the youtube id/url from the youtube embed url. Not having much regular expression (don't have to be regular expression) experience,i am having hard time getting the url out from the embed url.
Does anyone what's the easiest way to do it?

http://pastebin.com/708GPJnR

Comment: Please can you copy/paste few lines of your code for me

Comment: that's weird. i added the embed url but doesn't work for some reason. ok posted in pastebin.

Comment: its probably being interpreted as html and being filtered.  I'll just grab a random one

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1773972/56778

Comment: In addition, you'll find that embed code differs wildly. Trying to identify the video URL in the embed code using regular expressions will be ... unreliable, at best. Your solution will work for the case you test, but will fail on some other site that uses a different type of embed. You're better off parsing the HTML with an HTML parser, extracting the URLs, and then using a regular expression to get the video id.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't appear to be a complete youtube video id.  As I understand it, youtube video id's are 11 characters long.

That said, I modified your sample embedded URL to be 11 characters (by adding 1's at the end) and used a combination of XML and the regex referred to in the comments of your question ([stackoverflow.com/a/1773972/56778](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1773972/56778)) to do the following:

```
var xmlFrag = @"<object width='530' height='319'>
                  <param name='movie' value='**http://www.youtube.com/v/973r7347&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0**' />
                  <param name='allowFullScreen' value='true' />
                  <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always' />
                  <embed src='http://www.youtube.com/v/973r7347111&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1&amp;rel=0' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' width='530' height='319'></embed>
                </object>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlFrag);
var match = Regex.Match(doc.SelectSingleNode("/object/embed").Attributes["src"].Value,
                                          "^http://(?<domain>([^./]+\\.)*youtube\\.com)(/v/|/watch\\?v=)(?<videoId>[A-Za-z0-9_-]{11})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

String youtubeId;
if (match.Success)
  youtubeId = match.Groups[4].Value;
```

Comment: You should really make a Nuget package