# PHP: RegEx match all URLs that are outside links

Tags: php, regex

so far i've been using this regex code to get the ID of a YouTube video

```
"/https?:\/\/w*.?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)\/watch\/\?v=([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/i"
```

i tried extending it, so it would ignore IDs of YouTube videos in HTML links (href="..")

```
"/[?:(^href=\")]https?:\/\/w*.?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)\/watch\/\?v=([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/i"
```

unfortunately, that's not doing it. in fact the full code produces the opposite result.

```
$input = array(
    'http://youtube.com/watch/?v=oKay1',
    'http://youtu.be/watch/?v=oKay2',
    'href="http://youtube.com/watch/?v=NICHToKay"', //this shouldn't be found
    '[url="http://youtube.com/watch/?v=oKay3]'
    );

$pattern = "/[?:(^href=\")]https?:\/\/w*.?(?:youtube.com|youtu.be)\/watch\/\?v=([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)/i";

foreach($input as $v) {
    $match = preg_match_all($pattern, $v, $result);
    print "$v => $match\n";
    if ($match == 1)
        var_dump($result);
}
```

any help please?

Comment: Why not `strip_tags()` first, and then look for URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (based on your 4 given values in the arrays):

```
/^(\[url\="){0,1}http[s]{0,1}\:\/\/(www\.){0,1}(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/watch\/\?v\=(.+)(\]){0,1}/ims
```

you will get your ID in 3rd array of results

Answer (score 0):

Try this , i got it from another link on this site

```
preg_match('#<object[^>]+>.+?http://www.youtube.com/v/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+).+?</object>#s', $markup, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Source : [Get Youtube Video ID from html code with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773822/get-youtube-video-id-from-html-code-with-php)